# JIRA: /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/notify - How to specify recipients

Tags: jira-rest-api

Been stuck with this. Does anyone know how to specify the recipients? I assumed the "to" specifies recipients but I still get an error that no recipients were specified.

Answer (score 2):

from https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e3102

You can nest an array of users under `to`, like this:

```
"to": {
  "users": [
      {
        "name": "username_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "username_2"
      }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Note the user has to exist, and the user cannot be admin